# WooCommerce Custom Field does not save to DB ... sometimes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've had approximately 10,000 orders on a Woo-commerce website.  About 0.4% did not save the required custom field 'custom_location'.  I have no idea how this is possible and can't find a way to reproduce.

Also, I use the selected value of the field to save a secondary value to the DB.   The secondary value gets saved correctly, even when 'custom_location' is null in the DB.  Clearly, $_POST['custom_location'] contains valid data, but it's not saved... why?

```
// Here I create the custom select field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // <select> options
    $args = array('post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true);
    $locations = get_posts($args);
    $ops = array('default' => 'Select a location');
    foreach($locations as $l) {
        $ops[$l->ID] =  __($l->post_title, 'woocommerce' );
    }
    // Add 'custom_location' field to 'shipping'
    $fields['shipping'] = array( 'custom_location' => array(
        'label'       => __('Location', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('', 'empty', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => false,
        'type'        => 'select',
        'options'     => $ops
        ))
        + $fields['shipping'];

     return $fields;
}
// Save related data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_extra_data' );
function save_extra_data( $order_id ) {
    $loc = $_POST['custom_location'];

    // This was saved correctly to DB even when 'custom_location' is null in DB!
    $meta = get_post_meta($loc, 'extra-shipping-data', true);
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_extra', $meta ); 
}
```

Comment: Where is defined your `$locations` variable used in the foreach loop?

Comment: I added the $locations var to the code.  It's an array of posts I get via "get_posts()"

Answer (score 0):

Your location will be saved null if the customer billing and shipping address are same. In your code, the declaration for `locations` is missing. With a slight change, you can minimize the code and effort. Make sure you replace `ops` with you options.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // <select> options
    $ops = array('default' => 'Select a location', 'location1' => 'Location 1');

    // Add 'custom_location' field to 'shipping'
    $fields['shipping'] = array( 'shipping_custom_location' => array(
        'label'       => __('Location', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('', 'empty', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => false,
        'type'        => 'select',
        'options'     => $ops
     ))
    + $fields['shipping'];

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: In this application shipping address is always different from billing, so we don't allow it to be optional.  I added the locations declaration a little while ago, sorry you missed that.  (btw, $ops does need to be editable by admins, which is why the get_posts code is there)

Comment: Have you tried changing the id from  `custom_location` to `shipping_custom_location`? It should work.

Comment: @LearnWoo your comment is really helpful, I solved my issue.